# What is the encoding getting used in tf.gfile.GFile()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, encoding

tf.gfile.GFile() does not accept an 'encoding' argument. from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4584) i gathered that gfile returns only a byte stream but that seems to have changed now as:

```
with tf.gfile.GFile("./data/squad/test1.txt", mode = "rb") as file1:
    print(file1.read(n = 2), type(file1.read(n = 2)))
with tf.gfile.GFile("./data/squad/test1.txt", mode = "r") as file1:
    print(file1.read(n = 2), type(file1.read(n = 2)))
```

output:

```
b'as' <class 'bytes'>
as <class 'str'>
```

So what exactly is the encoding that it uses while reading those strings? Is it utf8 or is it platform dependent as in the case of open protocol in python?

Comment: My understanding is that it's mimicking python's behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand the implementation, `tf.io.gfile.GFile` is always using UTF-8: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b3376f73ccfd6ae8721a946daf064675ee19b427/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py#L100

```py
def write(self, file_content):
  """Writes file_content to the file. Appends to the end of the file."""
  self._prewrite_check()
  self._writable_file.append(compat.as_bytes(file_content))
```

It is converting `str` to `bytes` using [`tf.compat.as_bytes`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/as_bytes) which encode to UTF-8:

Answer (score 0):

Is just a `byte-stream` so is up to you to know what is the byte-encoding of your text.

You can use a library to detect the encoding and use that as the decoding method. As of today (June 2020) one of the best python libraries for encoding detection is [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) by the awesome guys at Mozilla

```
pip install chardet
```

If you know is 'utf-8' you can decode it using

```py
import chardet

bstream = file1.read()
info = chardet.detect(bstream)
enc = info['encoding']
info['confidence']
text = bstream.decode(enc)
```